# Searching through a .txt file to get specific lines and outputting to a new file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a `.txt` file which is very large, divided into columns separated by (I think) a tab.

The columns are as such (obtained by running `head NAMEOFTEXTFILE.txt`):

```
CANVAS_CHROM    CANVAS_START    CANVAS_END      CANVAS_GT       CANVAS_RC       CANVAS_BC       CANVAS_CN       CANVAS_FILTER  CANVAS_QUAL      BRIDGE_ID       ILMN_ID PROJECT InferredSex     ensembl_gene_IDs        external_gene_IDs       Gene_database  Gene_biotype     overlap_ctrl    overlap_internal        overlap_PAR
```

I want to filter this by `Bridge ID`. Each ID is a three letter acronym for a disease, e.g., `IDM` for "insulin dependent diabetes" followed by a serial number for that specific patient such that `IDM131289748937` would be the genetic data for that patient. Each line in the table represents a different mutation.

I would then like to output this to a `.txt` file.

So far (using the command line) I have tried:

```
grep "IDM" $(find .. -name 'NAMEOFTEXTFILE.txt') > filtereddata.txt
```

but this outputs a garbled list of data.

I also tried:

```
`awk '/IDM3/' NAMEOFTEXTFILE.txt` > filtereddata.txt
```

and this also did not work.

I was wondering which function would be best suited for this task.

I have attached a sample of the raw text file below:

> CANVAS_CHROM    CANVAS_START    CANVAS_END      CANVAS_GT       CANVAS_RC       CANVAS_BC       CANVAS_CN       CANVAS_FILTER CANVAS_QUAL     BRIDGE_ID       ILMN_ID PROJECT InferredSex     ensembl_gene_IDs        external_gene_IDs    Gene_database    Gene_biotype    overlap_ctrl    overlap_internal        overlap_PAR
>   1       825226  916134  0/1     145     87      3       .       53      M006429 LP2000749-DNA_C03       PMG     F    ENSG00000272438,ENSG00000230699,ENSG00000241180,ENSG00000223764,ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000268179,ENSG00000188976,ENSG00000187961,ENSG00000187583,ENSG00000187642        RP11-54O7.16,RP11-54O7.1,RP11-54O7.2,RP11-54O7.3,SAMD11,AL645608.1,NOC2L,KLHL17,PLEKHN1,C1orf170      Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Ensembl),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol lincRNA,lincRNA,lincRNA,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding     0       1       0
>   1       826236  3641787 0/1     126     2655    3       .       61      E009248 LP2000862-DNA_G05       PAH     F    ENSG00000272438,ENSG00000230699,ENSG00000241180,ENSG00000223764,ENSG00000187634,ENSG00000268179,ENSG00000188976,ENSG00000187961,ENSG00000187583,ENSG00000187642,ENSG00000272512,ENSG00000188290,ENSG00000231702,ENSG00000224969,ENSG00000187608,ENSG00000188157,ENSG00000242590,ENSG00000217801,ENSG00000273443,ENSG00000237330,ENSG00000131591,ENSG00000223823,ENSG00000207730,ENSG00000207607,ENSG00000198976,ENSG00000272141,ENSG00000205231,ENSG00000162571,ENSG00000186891,ENSG00000186827,ENSG00000078808,ENSG00000176022,ENSG00000184163,ENSG00000260179,ENSG00000160087,ENSG00000230415,ENSG00000162572,ENSG00000131584,ENSG00000169972,ENSG00000127054,ENSG00000240731,ENSG00000224051,ENSG00000169962,ENSG00000107404,ENSG00000162576,ENSG00000175756,ENSG00000223663,ENSG00000221978,ENSG00000224870,ENSG00000242485,ENSG00000264293,ENSG00000272455,ENSG00000235098,ENSG00000225905,ENSG00000205116,ENSG00000225285,ENSG00000179403,ENSG00000215915,ENSG00000160072,ENSG00000197785,ENSG00000205090,ENSG00000160075,ENSG00000215791,ENSG00000215014,ENSG00000236684,ENSG00000228594,ENSG00000272106,ENSG00000197530,ENSG00000189409,ENSG00000248333,ENSG00000272004,ENSG00000189339,ENSG00000269737,ENSG00000269227,ENSG00000215914,ENSG00000008128,ENSG00000268575,ENSG00000227775,ENSG00000215790,ENSG00000008130,ENSG00000078369,ENSG00000231050,ENSG00000169885,ENSG00000178821,ENSG00000142609,ENSG00000233542,ENSG00000187730,ENSG00000226969,ENSG00000067606,ENSG00000271806,ENSG00000182873,ENSG00000162585,ENSG00000269554,ENSG00000203301,ENSG00000243558,ENSG00000234396,ENSG00000157933,ENSG00000116151,ENSG00000272161,ENSG00000269753,ENSG00000269896,ENSG00000238240,ENSG00000272420,ENSG00000271921,ENSG00000271847,ENSG00000178642,ENSG00000157916,ENSG00000157911,ENSG00000149527,ENSG00000224387,ENSG00000229393,ENSG00000157881,ENSG00000197921,ENSG00000272449,ENSG00000238164,ENSG00000157873,ENSG00000225931,ENSG00000228037,ENSG00000157870,ENSG00000142606,ENSG00000237058,ENSG00000215912,ENSG00000233234,ENSG00000231630,ENSG00000169717,ENSG00000177133,ENSG00000256761,ENSG00000142611,ENSG00000226286,ENSG00000272235,ENSG00000130762,ENSG00000272088,ENSG00000162591,ENSG00000207776,ENSG00000238260,ENSG00000158109,ENSG00000116213,ENSG00000078900,ENSG00000227589,ENSG00000235131   RP11-54O7.16,RP11-54O7.1,RP11-54O7.2,RP11-54O7.3,SAMD11,AL645608.1,NOC2L,KLHL17,PLEKHN1,C1orf170,RP11-54O7.17,HES4,RP11-54O7.10,RP11-54O7.11,ISG15,AGRN,RP11-54O7.14,RP11-465B22.3,RP11-54O7.18,RNF223,C1orf159,RP11-465B22.5,MIR200B,MIR200A,MIR429,RP11-465B22.8,TTLL10-AS1,TTLL10,TNFRSF18,TNFRSF4,SDF4,B3GALT6,FAM132A,RP5-902P8.12,UBE2J2,RP5-902P8.10,SCNN1D,ACAP3,PUSL1,CPSF3L,RP5-890O3.9,GLTPD1,TAS1R3,DVL1,MXRA8,AURKAIP1,RP5-890O3.3,CCNL2,RP4-758J18.2,MRPL20,RN7SL657P,RP4-758J18.13,ANKRD65,RP4-758J18.7,TMEM88B,RP4-758J18.10,VWA1,ATAD3C,ATAD3B,ATAD3A,TMEM240,SSU72,AL645728.2,AL645728.1,AL645728.3,C1orf233,RP11-345P4.9,MIB2,MMP23B,CDK11B,RP11-345P4.10,SLC35E2B,RP11-345P4.7,RP11-345P4.6,MMP23A,CDK11A,RP1-283E3.8,RP1-283E3.4,SLC35E2,NADK,GNB1,RP1-140A9.1,CALML6,TMEM52,C1orf222,RP11-547D24.1,GABRD,RP11-547D24.3,PRKCZ,RP5-892K4.1,RP11-181G12.2,C1orf86,AL590822.2,AL590822.1,RP11-181G12.5,RP11-181G12.4,SKI,MORN1,RP4-713A8.1,AL589739.1,RP4-740C4.6,RP4-740C4.5,RP4-740C4.7,RP4-740C4.9,RP4-740C4.8,AL513477.1,RER1,PEX10,PLCH2,RP3-395M20.2,RP3-395M20.3,PANK4,HES5,RP3-395M20.12,RP3-395M20.8,TNFRSF14,RP3-395M20.7,RP3-395M20.9,FAM213B,MMEL1,RP13-436F16.1,TTC34,RP11-740P5.2,RP11-740P5.3,ACTRT2,LINC00982,AL008733.1,PRDM16,RP1-163G9.2,RP11-22L13.1,ARHGEF16,RP11-168F9.2,MEGF6,MIR551A,RP11-46F15.2,TPRG1L,WRAP73,TP73,RP5-1092A11.5,RP5-1092A11.2 Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Ensembl),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Ensembl),Clone-based (Ensembl),Clone-based (Ensembl),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Ensembl),Clone-based (Ensembl),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Ensembl),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Ensembl),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Ensembl),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega) lincRNA,lincRNA,lincRNA,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,pseudogene,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,sense_intronic,pseudogene,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,miRNA,miRNA,miRNA,lincRNA,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,sense_intronic,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,pseudogene,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,misc_RNA,lincRNA,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,pseudogene,protein_coding,pseudogene,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,antisense,pseudogene,pseudogene,protein_coding,processed_transcript,pseudogene,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,antisense,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,sense_intronic,protein_coding,processed_transcript,pseudogene,sense_intronic,sense_intronic,sense_intronic,pseudogene,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,processed_transcript,protein_coding,antisense,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,protein_coding,lincRNA,lincRNA,protein_coding,antisense,pseudogene,protein_coding,antisense,lincRNA,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,miRNA,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,antisense,antisense 0       1       0
>   1       969935  1231975 0/1     145     252     3       .       61      E005981 LP2000742-DNA_D01       PAH     M    ENSG00000188157,ENSG00000242590,ENSG00000217801,ENSG00000273443,ENSG00000237330,ENSG00000131591,ENSG00000223823,ENSG00000207730,ENSG00000207607,ENSG00000198976,ENSG00000272141,ENSG00000205231,ENSG00000162571,ENSG00000186891,ENSG00000186827,ENSG00000078808,ENSG00000176022,ENSG00000184163,ENSG00000260179,ENSG00000160087,ENSG00000230415,ENSG00000162572,ENSG00000131584    AGRN,RP11-54O7.14,RP11-465B22.3,RP11-54O7.18,RNF223,C1orf159,RP11-465B22.5,MIR200B,MIR200A,MIR429,RP11-465B22.8,TTLL10-AS1,TTLL10,TNFRSF18,TNFRSF4,SDF4,B3GALT6,FAM132A,RP5-902P8.12,UBE2J2,RP5-902P8.10,SCNN1D,ACAP3 HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,Clone-based (Vega),HGNC Symbol,HGNC Symbol      protein_coding,sense_intronic,pseudogene,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,miRNA,miRNA,miRNA,lincRNA,antisense,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,lincRNA,protein_coding,protein_coding 0       2       0
>   1       1025358 1068256 0/1     141     43      3       .       25      G012138 LP2000955-DNA_A12       SPEED   M    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       4       0
>   1       1027213 1054981 0/1     122     31      3       .       17      C003646 LP2000719-DNA_D01       GEL     F    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       6       0
>   1       1027429 1054789 0/1     120     30      3       .       17      C003121 LP2000712-DNA_D08       GEL     F    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       6       0
>   1       1027747 1054977 0/1     127     27      3       .       15      C001669 LP2000262-DNA_B10       GEL     F    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       6       0
>   1       1028234 1047162 0/1     116     21      3       .       11      C002886 LP2000275-DNA_C06       GEL     M    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       6       0
>   1       1028342 1046413 0/1     122     20      3       .       11      C001874 LP2000266-DNA_H03       GEL     F    ENSG00000131591  C1orf159        HGNC Symbol     protein_coding  0       6       0

Comment: Please, post some sample data, such that we can test against, along with the expected output.

Comment: Ignore all of the grep solutions as they operate across the whole line, not a specific column, and so are highly prone to false matches. The correct answer will be an awk script and we can help you with that ones you do as @JamesBrown asks so we can get a complete understanding of the problem.

Comment: Dear @james Brown, many thanks for your response. I have attached some sample data below the original questions (by using head 50 NAMEOFTEXTFILE.txt)

Comment: Where is "IDM" in your sample file?

Comment: You have posted a single line that appear to be headers for your actual data. Best I can tell from your question, you are interested in the `BRIDGE_ID` field and some number after it, but you are completely unclear on what you need from that point forward. Please help us help you be explaining with particular clarity what you need out of the headings you have posted and what from the data that also presumably exists in the same file.

Comment: Apologies if I am not being clear. Each line in the file represents a single mutation found in a patients DNA. There are >1000 patients in this text file. Each patient is given an ID based on their disease. This is defined in the BRIDGE_ID column, although I am not 100% sure of this.

Comment: I see only one string in your sample file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use simple grep "IDM" it searches for string "IDM" at any part of a word (i.e) starting, middle, etc.

As I am not sure the text "IDM31234234" is exist exactly where on a line. Hence I am assuming Line starts with "IDM31234234".

```
egrep "^IDM[0-9]+ " inputfile > output file #this searches for the line which starts with IDM with one minimal integer and there is a space after that
```

If you are sure about the number of integers then you can make as below

```
 egrep "^IDM[0-9]{7} "  inputfile > output file # IDM with 7 integers
 egrep "^IDM[0-9]{7,} "  inputfile > output file # IDM with minimal 7 integers
```

In simple term, use regular expression in more effective to narrow the search. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Split the file into lines with one word in the line and `grep` for IDM

```
tr " " "\n" < NAMEOFTEXTFILE.txt | grep IDM > OUTPUTFILE.txt
```

use `"\t"` columns separated by a tab or `" "` if columns separated by a space.